# Non blocking sockets arent receiving any writes from server

Tags: java, sockets

I have Socket server using non-blocking sockets:

```
public class NonBlockingMessageQueue implements MessageQueue {

    private final Map<SelectionKey, LocalDateTime> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    private Selector selector;
    private ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;

    @Override
    public void start(int port) {
        try {
            initSelector();
            listenToSockets();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void initSelector() throws IOException {
        this.selector = Selector.open();
        this.serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 1234));
        serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    }

    private void listenToSockets() throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            if (selector.select() <= 0)
                continue;
            Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
                keyMap.put(key, LocalDateTime.now());
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    SocketChannel sc = serverSocketChannel.accept();
                    sc.configureBlocking(false);
                    sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    System.out.println("Connection Accepted: " + sc.getLocalAddress() + "n");
                }

                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    boolean exists = keyMap.containsKey(key);
                    SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                    sc.read(bb);
                    String result = new String(bb.array()).trim();
                    messages.add(result);


                    for( SelectionKey channel : keyMap.keySet()) {
                        try {
                            SelectableChannel chan = channel.channel();
                            if( (chan.validOps() & SelectionKey.OP_WRITE ) > 0) {
                                ByteBuffer bbb = ByteBuffer.wrap(messages.get(0).getBytes());
                                                             ((SocketChannel)chan).write(bbb);
                            }
                        }catch (Throwable e ){
                            System.out.println("Error " + e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then i have two clients, one for writing and one for reading:

```
    public class NonBlockingClientWrite {
        private static BufferedReader input = null;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(
                    InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 1234);
            Selector selector = Selector.open();
            SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open();
            sc.configureBlocking(false);
            sc.connect(addr);
            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while (true) {
                if (selector.select() > 0) {
                    Boolean doneStatus = processReadySet
                            (selector.selectedKeys());
                    if (doneStatus) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            sc.close();
        }
        public static Boolean processReadySet(Set readySet)
                throws Exception {
            SelectionKey key = null;
            Iterator iterator = null;
            iterator = readySet.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
            }
            if (key.isConnectable()) {
                Boolean connected = processConnect(key);
                if (!connected) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (key.isWritable()) {
                System.out.print("Type a message (type quit to stop): ");
                String msg = input.readLine();
                if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                    return true;
                }
                SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(msg.getBytes());
                sc.write(bb);
            }
            return false;
        }
        public static Boolean processConnect(SelectionKey key) {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            try {
                while (sc.isConnectionPending()) {
                    sc.finishConnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                key.cancel();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And read:

```
public class NonBlockingClientRead {
    private static BufferedReader input = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 1234);
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open();
        sc.configureBlocking(false);
        sc.connect(addr);
        sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        while (true) {
            if (selector.select() > 0) {
                Boolean doneStatus = processReadySet(selector.selectedKeys());
                if (doneStatus) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    public static Boolean processReadySet(Set readySet) throws Exception {
        SelectionKey key = null;
        Iterator iterator = null;
        iterator = readySet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
        }
        if (key.isConnectable()) {
            Boolean connected = processConnect(key);
            if (!connected) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (key.isReadable()) {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            sc.read(bb);
            String result = new String(bb.array()).trim();
            System.out.println("Message received from Server: " + result + " Message length= "
                    + result.length());
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static Boolean processConnect(SelectionKey key) {
        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        try {
            while (sc.isConnectionPending()) {
                sc.finishConnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            key.cancel();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basicly, whenever i receive message from write client, i want to send it to read server ( the most primitive MQ example), however whenver i send data to the client, it is not receiving any messages, why?

Also

1. when i store the `SelectionKey` in a map , i have two types ,`SocketChannel` and `ServerSocketChannelImpl` , where does the `ServerSocketChannelImpl` comes from?

[image]

2. When i check ops for writing the socket, both `SocketChannel` in map ( i assume they are from clients have OP_WRITE flag set , e.g

```
chan.validOps() & SelectionKey.OP_WRITE
```

results true for both of them , even tho i explicitly set one for `OP_READ` and one for `OP_WRITE`, how is this possible?

3. if i add `if( key.isWritable())` in server logic, it always goes into this branch, white? I assume `isReadable()` is true only when there is message in channel, so what is the purpose of `isWritable()` if we send directly messages with `channel.write(buffer)` ? And why is it always true?

Thanks for help!

Comment: In the processConnect method of NonBlockingClientRead, add some println statements to inform you of whether the method is returning and what value it is returning.

Comment: I added those println messages and it works for me.  Can you characterize better why you think this code doesn't work?  (The code does have a problem when the client closes its connection, but that's not directly the problem here.)

Comment: You should not register for `SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);``OP_WRITE` is true as long as there is space in the send buffer, which is nearly always the case. You only use `OP_WRITE` after a zero-length write, and you stop using it immediately the send buffer starts accepting writes again. And after processing `OP_CONNECT` successfully you should remove it from the key's `interestOps`.